# JAVA Fx and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javafx, efxclipse

I can't find my answer anywhere

I know javafx is now part of the SDK as of java 8 release and late java 7 release.

I am using Eclipse and scene builder 8 to build an app for a school project.

I want to know if the teacher needs to install e(fx)clipse to run the app so it will work properly ?

Also I am using a maven build for Junit dependencies do I need to add any javaFx library ? for it to work (even tho its already part of the sdk)

Thank you

Comment: Not if you create a standalone `Jar` or `EXE` with all the resources to support.

Comment: @Sedrick I need to submit the whole source code and library dependencies needs to be managed by Maven.

Comment: As long as the other user is also running Oracle JDK 8 (or later), it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know if the teacher needs to install e(fx)clipse to run the app so it will work properly ?

No, e(fx)clipse is not mandatory for building JavaFX apps. If you don't have a highly complex app, you will be fine without efxclipse.

> Also I am using a maven build for Junit dependencies do I need to add any javaFx library ? for it to work (even tho its already part of the sdk)

No if you're using Oracle Java JDK 8, you don't need to add any `JavaFX` library.

A good tutorial to start with JavaFX apps is http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/, I found it useful when I started out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! This is the answer I was looking for. Do you know if GLUON build for scene builder will add some functionality that I might need to import. (I saw they add specific buttons released for the gluon theme) Thank you

Comment: Thanks, you can mark it as the accepted answer to help others who end up here. I'm not sure if I completely understand your question, but scene builder is a separate application that you can use to inspect a running JavaFX app (similar to Chrome Dev Tools for HTML apps). You wouldn't need to import anything to use Scene builder, which you can find here http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/